# How to remove a part of URL by using regex in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some URL look likes:

```
<loc>http://www.website.com/category/keyword1-keyowrd2-v894545</loc>
<loc>http://www.website.com/category/keyword1-v3650159</loc>
<loc>http://www.website.com/category/keyword1-keyword2-keyword3-v35460159</loc>
```

How to remove "-v894545", "-v3650159", and "-v35460159" at last of URL in notedpad ++ ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work !

Comment: I've tried out @vks solution, and it worked for me. Put -v\d+$ in the Find what input box, and an empty string to the Replace with. Search mode: regular expresson. And click replace all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-v\d+$
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.

Comment: Yes, your code works with old URL. However, I changed my URL. So, how to apply it with my new URL. Sorry, it is my mistake !

Comment: @Jee try `-v\d+(?=\s*<)`

Comment: try `-v\d+(?=\s*<\/[^<>]*>$)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last part of the string along with `-`, do :

```
1. Open replace window
2. Select `Wrap Around` checkBox and `Regular Expression` radio button.
3. Put `-[^\-]+$` in `Find what` text field and `</loc>` in `Replace with`
4. Press `Replace All`
```

Comment: change your Regex `-[^\-]+$` with `-v\d+`. Or `Replace with = </loc>`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I can't +1 for you because of my reputation. Sorry !

Comment: u don't have to be, but soon you will be able to. Cheers :-)